# dpkg-shlibdeps do not give version information

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, dynamic-linking

I am creating a package that depends on the ROS package ros-noetic-moveit-core. More specifically, it contains a shared library linking against `libmoveit_robot_model.so`.

`libmoveit_robot_model.so` is i a symbolic link to `libmoveit_robot_model.so.1.1.7`, so `libmoveit_robot_model.so.1.1.7` ends in the NEEDED section of my shared library.

However, when I package it, dpkg-shlibdeps only adds `ros-noetic-moveit-core` to the shlibs depends, without any version information.

When MoveIt! update to a newer version, like it did when updating from 1.1.6, the library `libmoveit_robot_model.so.1.1.7` will be replaced by `libmoveit_robot_model.so.1.1.8` (for example), and my package will no longer link, while dpkg do not see the conflict.

How can I make sure that my package correctly inform of its dependencies? I see two solutions:

- Find a way to not include the version suffix when linking so my package is compatible with multiple version of MoveIt!, but I do not like this solution (especially since MoveIt! do not provides a *symbols* file or event a symbolic link with a major version suffix, like `libmoveit_robot_model.so.1`).
- Find a way to make dpkg-shlibdeps find the used version of MoveIt! so my package is upgraded alongside MoveIt!.

If it is an error from the MoveIt! packager, what can they do, and what can I do while waiting for the packages to be fixed?

More information on MoveIt!:

- I am using [this .deb package](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-noetic-moveit-core/ros-noetic-moveit-core_1.1.7-1focal.20220107.014110_amd64.deb).
- There is no *.symbols* file.
- The file /var/lib/dpkg/info/ros-noetic-moveit-core.shlibs contains the following:

```
#...
libmoveit_robot_model 1.1.7 ros-noetic-moveit-core
#...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a packaging problem (and arguably, a library definition problem). Before I get to that, here’s what you can do to fix it: you can specify your own `shlibs` line, either in `debian/shlibs.local` in your package’s source code, or in `/etc/dpkg/shlibs.override`. Add a line of the form

```
libmoveit_robot_model 1.1.7 ros-noetic-moveit-core (>= 1.1.7), ros-noetic-moveit-core (<< 1.1.8)
```

to tie your package to 1.1.7 versions of the `ros-noetic-moveit-core` package.

As for `ros-noetic-moveit-core` itself, it should ship its libraries in a package whose name reflects the package’s soname. If each version of the package isn’t backwards-compatible, then that name should include the full version (so it’s repeated, in the package name as well as its metadata). If versions 1.1.8 is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for 1.1.7, then the soname should stop at 1.1 or even 1. The relevant chapter of Debian Policy, which describes best practices relevant not only for Debian, is [the chapter on shared libraries](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html). [This footnote](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html#id7) gives a command to calculate the appropriate package name for a library.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there a debhelper tool for them (or me) to generate a correct shlibs file?

Comment: Found it, It's dh_makeshlibs. Also, bloom (ROS and MoveIt! packaging tool) has an issue on this: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/426